# Fragment Pagination - Replacing Touch Handler

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an app with many tabs (like many iPhone apps), using the fragments navigation inside tabs. I'm using Support V4 lib.

So the framework is:
TabActivity->FragmentActivity->Fragments

In the fragment activity, the app will call this method to replace a new fragment:

```
public void updateFragment(Fragment fragment) { 

    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment, nTag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

... and in the new fragment I also ask the root view to handle the OnTouchEvent:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopfilter, container,
            false);
    root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

The previous fragment still gets the touch event, how do I make only the new fragment get the touch event?

Comment: Next time please write clearer, that was a b*** and a half to edit

Comment: HI. Christian, i have edited my question, pls help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is working, I just made a mistake.

In new fragment listview adapter, app will start a new empty fragment. But I forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

You're registering the fragment as the handler of that event, therefore if you want it to not get the touch event, you have to unregister. You can use `root.setOnTouchListener(null);` to unset it before setting a new one.

Comment: the logic is: AFragment->BFragment, So, the BFragment will over AFragment, then i set  ontouchlistener to BFragment's rootview, hope that can prevent click on AFragment.  But AFragment still reacts to click if i click space part int BFragment